# Bash while loop to compare two files and print line number

Tags: bash, while-loop, compare, line-numbers

I have file1:

```
A
B
C
D
```

I have file2:

```
B
C
```

I want to use a while read loop to go through both files compare them and print out the line number of file1 for any matching lines.

```
COUNT=0
while read line
do
    flag = 0
    while read line2
    do
    COUNT=$(( $COUNT + 1 ))
       if ( "$line" = "$line2" )
        then
            flag = 1
        fi
     done < file1
     if ( flag -eq 1 )
     then
         echo $COUNT > file3
     fi
done < file2
```

However I get an error: B command not found

Please could someone let me know where I have gone wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to count how many times a line of `file1` repeats in `file2`?

Comment: `grep -f file2 -n file1`?

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a lot of errors in this code, but to answer the question, the reason you are getting `B command not found` is because........ we use `[]` rather than `()` in bash.

other errors include:

```
COUNT=0
while read line
do
    flag=0         # no space between flag and =
    while read line2
    do
    COUNT=$(( $COUNT + 1 ))
    echo $line
    echo $line2

       if [ "_$line" = "_$line2" ]
        then
            flag=1         #no space again
        fi
     done < file1
     if [ $flag -eq 1 ]       # use $flag rather than flag
     then
         echo $COUNT > file3
     fi
done < file2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also achieve what you are looking for using `grep -c` like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Clean file3 
>file3

while read line; do
    COUNT=$(grep -c "^$line$" file2)

    if [ $COUNT -ge 1 ]; then
        $COUNT >> file3
    fi
done < file1
```

`grep -c` prints the number of times an expression matches the file content.